# how to query mongodb by passing parameter

Tags: angularjs

```
exports.search = function(req, res){Song.find({genre: req.param.genre}).exec(function(err, songs){

        console.log(req.param);
        if (err) {
            return res.send(400, {
                message: getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        }
        else {
            res.jsonp(songs);
        }

    });

};
```

Comment: You might want to actually ask a question and not only paste some code in here..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everybody for the time to review my code. What I wanted to do was to pass in a parameter into the search function and then retrieve everything in relation to the search so this code works for me......

for the route controller:

```
app.route('/songs/:genre')
        .get(songs.search);
```

for the server controller:

```
 exports.search = function(req, res){
    if( req.params.genre){
        Song.find({genre: req.params.genre }, function(err, songs){
            console.log(req.params.genre);
            res.json(songs);
        });
    }

};
```